# definition file: multiple possible types for property

Tags: typescript

I'm writing some definitions for an existing JS library (CKEditor). Is it possible to be more specific than `toolbar: any`?

Documentation:

> toolbar : Array/String
>
> The toolbox (alias toolbar) definition. It is a toolbar name or an
>   array of toolbars (strips), each one being also an array, containing a
>   list of UI items.

Library code:

```
var toolbar = editor.config.toolbar;

// If it is a string, return the relative "toolbar_name" config.
if ( typeof toolbar == 'string' )
    toolbar = editor.config[ 'toolbar_' + toolbar ];

return ( editor.toolbar = toolbar ? populateToolbarConfig( toolbar ) : buildToolbarConfig() );
```

Comment: Did you ever finish this? I was just about to start doing exactly the same thing for an open-source extension (https://github.com/bherila/integrated-editor) and if you had code you could share it would save me lots of time! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BenH I only did the functions I needed at the time, it's not much but I've put it on https://gist.github.com/stijnherreman/6316394

Comment: cool, thanks for sharing. I've also started and my code is here in case you're interested. https://github.com/bherila/integrated-editor/blob/master/ckeditor_n2tokens/ICKEditor.d.ts

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Typescript 1.4 now supports union types

Of course you still have to check the value inside the function and react accordingly, but now you can get compile time checking without having to change the type to `any`.

```
function f(x: number | number[]) {
  if (typeof x === "number") {
    return x + 10;
  }
  else {
    // return sum of numbers
  }
}
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Typescript does not support union types and is unlikely to do so [in the near future](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/120).

There are two suggestions made in the thread:

1. Function overloading
2. Generics

In the given piece of code, I cannot see anyway of avoiding the `any` type. However, outside the snippet, if the `toolbar` argument is being passed as an argument, function overloading might be able to express the type of those.

Comment: Tere is an issue on Codeplex that you can vote upon for a new feature as union types are quite common in JS frameworks https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1364

Answer (score 1):

You could model that the toolbar is an Array **and** a string.

```
interface ArrayAndString extends Array, String { }
var toolbar: ArrayAndString = editor.config.toolbar;
```

That says that both array and string operations are legal, which isn't really true and doesn't give much better safety than `any`.  There's no way to model that it can be one or the other but not both.

Comment: This does not solve the problem because it makes the interface `ArrayAndString` inherit both from `Array` _and_ `String`, not `Array` _or_ `String`. The compiler will complain if the assignment is missing any function from any of the classes: [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20ArrayAndString%20extends%20Array%2C%20String%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Avar%20toolbar%3A%20ArrayAndString%20%3D%20%22toolbar%22%3B%0D%0Avar%20toolbar2%20%3A%20ArrayAndString%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%3B).

Comment: Yes that extra cast also sucks.